# Access callback evaluated on every page

Tags: 7, routes

I have a custom module with a menu entry that has a page callback and a access callback. However, every time I visit ***any*** page, the access callback is evaluated. Could somebody enlighten me?

```
function foo_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['foo'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'foo',
    'access callback' => 'foo_access_callback',
  );

  return $items;
}

function foo() {
  //...
}

function foo_access_callback() {
  error_log('This gets evaluated on every page.');
  return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Is your function called exactly `foo_access_callback`? If not, is it possible in naming your function you've inadvertently implemented a system/contrib hook that's being called on every page?

Comment: I've tried renaming it to something else (foo_ac), doesn't help.

Comment: Confirmed this is happening on a blank installation with just the required core and 'Foo' modules enabled. Only on front end pages though, the callback is _not_ fired for admin pages. Interesting...

Comment: And it's fired 4 times on the '/foo' page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something just dawned on me...if you have a menu on the page that links to the '/foo' page, Drupal will query the access callback to find out if the menu link can be shown.

Since you're not providing a `type` in your menu item, it will default to `MENU_NORMAL_ITEM` which will place it in the site's Navigation menu.

I would guess that's what's causing the function to be run at least once on every front end page, but not for the admin pages (where you probably won't have the same menus).

It's definitely what was causing the issue on the test installation I just set up for this.

Comment: I have changed the type to MENU_CALLBACK, but the access callback is still evaluated. I have no link to the menu item anywhere.

Comment: I was thinking along similar lines though.

Comment: I've just done a backtrace and it's definitely coming from the menu module. As soon as I remove the Navigation menu from the sidebar the callback stops getting evaluated. Do you have a link to the site per-chance?

Comment: Quick debugging exercise: install the Devel module and run `dpm(debug_backtrace());` in your access callback. Then you'll be able to see where the function was invoked from

Comment: Even with MENU_CALLBACK: function _menu_check_access ... menu_name (String, 10 characters ) navigation.

Comment: I deleted the menu entry in the menu_link table, cleared the cache and the callback seems to work. Looks like changing the type of the menu entry to MENU_CALLBACK and clearing the cache didn't clear the record in menu_link, so it was still bound to "navigation" menu.

Comment: Ah yeah that makes sense (I think!) Glad you got it sorted

Comment: Does it qualify as Drupal Core bug you think?

Comment: I wouldn't have thought so...from Drupal's point of view either the admin or the module implementer should probably clean up any menu link that's added. I might be wrong though